# Query by key and order by date

Tags: firebase

I have a database with a lot of "listings" structured as such:

[image: Listings]

I want to get 10 listings, starting or ending at a certain priority value, with a size value (child node) range between 9 and 10.5 and have the result ordered by date.

I've looked at an abundance of SO posts and Firebase examples, but I can't seem to find any solution.

Can it really be the case that this isn't possible in Firebase? It's quite a common use-case as far as I know.

**Is there any solution to this? If not, how would you get around it?**

Comment: Please share sample code as a starting point. Not everyone is familiar with Firebase. Also, why is this tagged [ios]?

Comment: You can currently call `orderBy` once in each query. So the only workaround would be to combine the properties that you are looking to use into a single property and order/filter on that.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432030/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to review the [Complex Queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries) in Firebase documentation.

Take a look at range queries.  `startAt()` and `endAt()` allow you to look for shoes with specific sizes by setting starting and ending points for your queries.

For example, if we wanted to find all shoes that are between `9` and `10.5`, combine `orderByChild()`, `startAt`, and `endAt`.  Something like:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
ref.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt("9").endAt("10.5").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

If you could provide a code sample, then it would make it easier to pinpoint the solution. You may have to tweak your data model if you want to order your query by multiple keys.