# Combining ".equalTo()" Queries in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

The equivalent in SQL would be this:

`SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE uid=:uid AND status=:active`

In firebase I have this so far:

`var myJobs = jobs.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(userID);`

I need to also filter by status, I was wondering what the best way to do that is?

Comment: Firebase allows only one `orderBy` on a query. This has been asked before, to I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do the following query in Firebase? (more than one where condition)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432030/how-to-do-the-following-query-in-firebase-more-than-one-where-condition)